# Count cells containing case-sensitive text when adjacent row is not blank

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to count the number of cells in column A that contains a case-sensitive value (since I'm dealing with words TTK and TTk differently). I was able to do this via the following formula `=COUNT(INDEX(FIND("TTK",$A:$A))`. The problem right now is that I need to count only column A cells that fit the above criteria, and if its adjacent row in column B is not blank. I've tried several methods like:

```
=COUNT(INDEX(FIND("TTK",$A:$A)*INDEX(FIND(<>"",$B:$B))
{=IF(""<>$B:$B,COUNT(INDEX(FIND("TTK",$A:$A)))}
```

but still these returned errors. I'm not sure where I'm wrong on these trials. I would appreciate your guidance on this matter. Thanks so much! :)

Sample data is as follows:

```
Column A       Column B
aTTKsss        (blank)
bTTKwww        (not blank)
sss TTKww      (blank)
w wTTKqqq      (not blank)
aaaTTkxx       (not blank)
ssfdsfTTkc     (not blank)
ss sdTTksss    (blank)
sqw TTk sdfqq  (blank)
```

As per the sample data, I want the count to output a value of 2 since in column A, we only have two cells containing a case-sensitive value of TTK while having a non-adjacent cell in column B.

Comment: Are you using [tag:excel] or [tag:google-spreadsheet]?  At first glance, looks like you could be using the [`COUNTIFS` function](https://support.office.com/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842), but a sample representative of your data would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg, I'm using google spreadsheet atm. However, I wish to have this solution be done in Excel also later on. I tried using COUNTIFS(), but it can't distinguish between "TTK" and "TTk" differently. Or if you have an alternate solution using this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: An example of your data would help.

Comment: @ashleedawg, provided sample data as requested. Hope this gives us a clearer view point of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This standard formula (non-CSE) should be sufficient.

```
=SUM(INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND("TTK", A:A))*(SIGN(LEN(B:B))), , ))
```

However, you might find substantial more efficiency if you cut down the full column reference.

```
=SUM(INDEX(ISNUMBER(FIND("TTK", A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A))))*(SIGN(LEN(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz", A:A))))), , ))
```

Comment: Very nice use of the `0` argument for the `INDEX` row and column arguments

Answer (score 1):

In a google spreadsheet, you could also try

```
=sumproduct(regexmatch(A2:A, "TTK"),B2:B<>"")
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(D1,A:A))*(LEN(B:B)>0))
```

The formula will be more efficient if you can use less than full column arguments for columns `A` and `B`