# Add Case Sensitivity to CountIf function

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I have some VBA code that doesn't differentiate between uppercase/lowercase values. As I've been looking around the site, I saw a lot about removing case sensitivity, but not about adding it. My understanding was that Excel VBA was case sensitive by default, but that seems to be false in my situation, or I managed to remove it unknowingly.

Here is an example: In Column E there are values such as E01, e01, E02, e02, etc. I need to treat the values with an uppercase E and a lowercase E differently. So in my below code when I state that `a = "E01"` I truly mean E01, not e01. However, both are being included when I run the VBA.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim FirstAddress As String, _
    cF As Range, _
    RowsToCopy As String
Dim a As String

a = "E01"

With ActiveSheet.Columns(5)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, a) > 1 Then
        Set cF = .Find(What:=a, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cF.Address
            Do
                cF.EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Sheets("Misc").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
```

Did I do something here to turn-off case sensitivity somehow? Any ideas on how I can make it so that this code sample does not include e01? Should I be adding something like `MatchCase:=True` somewhere in here?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You answered your own question - yes change `MatchCase:=False` to `MatchCase:=True`. More detail at [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel). But you really don't need `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf...`.

Comment: It's on the countif not the find part though @BigBen  I agree, the countif is not needed, if the count is 0 your find will be `nothing`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849356/count-cells-containing-case-sensitive-text-when-adjacent-row-is-not-blank/50850032#50850032

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, well put, if a case-sensitive count is 0 your find will be `nothing`.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the reply. I think the CountIf is actually needed for my purposes here. I didnt bother getting into detail about it since it didnt matter to this question, but what I'm doing is only taking action is there are 2 or more "E01", if there is only 1 "E01" then I want to skip over it. I think the countif was responsible for that. since i could have any number of "E01" depending on the day.

Comment: @TBoulz - ah, I glossed over the `>1` - in that case ignore my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I asked this, and I forgot to post the workaround I implemented, just in case anyone comes across this in the future.

I avoided the `.find` and instead used a sort, then a loop to check for some criteria.

*The Sort:*

```
.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=theRange.Columns(5).Cells, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=theRange.Columns(3).Cells, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        '***** Decide the format of the sort and apply the sorting *****
        With .Sort
            .SetRange theRange
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

*The Loop:*

```
lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
'***** Setting our range for the next loop *****
Set rng2 = Range("E2:E" & lr2)

For Each cell2 In rng2
    '***** IF statement for if the type ID is the same as the next row's type ID *****
    If cell2 = cell2.Offset(1) Then
        '***** Type ID is the same, so we check if it is also a R-D transaction *****
        If cell2.Value Like "*R-D*" Then
            cell2.Value = "R-D"
            '***** If this is a R-D transaction then we do not add the totals of the two lines. Column A total equals Column C total *****
            Total = Total + cell2.Offset(0, -2)
            '***** Placing the summed total into column F *****
            cell2.Offset(0, 1) = Total
            Total = 0
        '***** If the Type ID is the same and the date is different, then we do NOT add the totals together *****
        ElseIf cell2.Offset(0, -3) <> cell2.Offset(1, -3) Then
            Total = Total + cell2.Offset(0, -2)
            '***** Placing the summed total into column F *****
            cell2.Offset(0, 1) = Total
            Total = 0
        ElseIf cell2.Value Like "*ARC*" Then
            cell2.Value = "ARC"
            Total = Total + cell2.Offset(0, -2)
            cell2.Offset(0, 1) = Total
            Total = 0
        Else
        '***** If this is not a R-D or ARC then we add the two totals together and move on to the next row until we find a new Type ID *****
        Total = Total + cell2.Offset(0, -2)
        End If
    '***** If the type ID is not the same as the ID in the next row, then we just carry the trans amt over to Column A from Column C *****
    Else
        Total = Total + cell2.Offset(0, -2)
        '***** Placing the summed total into column F *****
        cell2.Offset(0, 1) = Total
        '***** Resetting the total variable to 0 so we do not add the next row's total to an existing total *****
        Total = 0
    End If
'***** Move on to the next cell and repeat the process *****
Next cell2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do want a case sensitive countif in the future

`=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT("A2",A1:A5))`

Use `SUMPRODUCT` on `EXACT`